# Page Display problem in asp.net: incorrect page layout?

Tags: asp.net

i developed a web application and it is working fine in local server. when i place the web application (copy paste the file of asp.net) in another local system it is working fine but the design of the page is (layout of the page) not as in the first server what could be the problem please help me.
the above image is not well formed.

Comment: There could be many reasons. Can you please provide us with the link?

Comment: no it is in local (our company server) link can't there

Comment: Do you update the css file as in your question you mention only the aspx files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be related to the fact that links to static resources such as images and CSS are hard-coded. You could use relative paths or try [specifying the base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp).

Comment: Mr. Darin Dimitrov i have to change the css?

Comment: I don't know what you have to change. So far you've shown 0 code.

Comment: I change the style sheet, like image urls but it is not dispalying all the content coming in vertical format

Comment: Ya Mr. Darin DImitrov i check the css change the image path it is working fine thank you